# Hide Controls on TabControl

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

Working in VS2013 VB, I have a TabControl that has Button controls on the various tabs, named Button1, Button2, etc. I want to set the visible property to false for all of the buttons during the form load, however it is not working. I am sure I am missing something simple, here is my code:

```
    Dim ctl As Control

    'Loop thru all controls
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls

        'Test that it is a Button and test for name
        If (TypeOf ctl Is Button And Mid(ctl.Name, 1, 6) = "Button") Then

            'Hide the Button
            ctl.Visible = False

        End If

    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to be looking at the tab page collection and the controls collection.
Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        hideButtons()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub hideButtons()

    For Each tp As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
        For Each ctl As Control In tp.Controls
            If (TypeOf ctl Is Button And Mid(ctl.Name, 1, 6) = "Button") Then
                ctl.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That code has an error on the "For Each ctl" ine, "Variable 'ctl' hides a variable in an enclosing block"

Comment: It'll be an error if you paste it into your code block and leave your 'Dim ctl as Control' statement, but I don't believe that statement is necessary any longer. So you can remove it. I've edited the code to show a working version.